# Numbers appear in scientifically notation in excel when data is exported from C# application

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, export-to-excel

```
        Excel.Application xlApp ;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0; 

        for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount  - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount  - 1; j++)
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;
            }
        }...
```

As you can see above, I am exporting data from a datagridview to an .xls file. The problem is that when the file is exported, that the data which is is more than 10 numbers or so, appears to be notated in scientifically notation when the file is opened in Excel. This results in dataloss. And I can't permit that myself because the data is a code rather than a count.

Comment: What do yo mean by "data which is is more than 10 numbers". Do you mean 10 digits ?

Comment: Did you try xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value.ToString();

Comment: @Pankaj yes I mean 10 digits

Comment: @HypnoToad yes I did try that, but unfortunately it didn't help...

Comment: 11 digits.  Happens when you type them into a spreadsheet by hand as well.  With the same fix you have to use in your code, you change the cell format.

Comment: I agree with Hans, either change the cell format or round the number to 10 digits before calling ToString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if a Cell.Value can be interpreted as a number, Excel will interpret it as a number. Unless the Cell.NumberFormat is Text ("@").

Try

```
...
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].NumberFormat = "@";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value
...
```

Greetings

Axel